# How to implement TURN first ICE connection with WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

In several WebRTC talks (by [Philipp Hanke](https://youtu.be/_OE-4woHv2E?t=1165) and [Chad Hart](https://youtu.be/JrxSDIJv5xs?t=935)) the subject of TURN or Relay first WebRTC connections is mentioned.

In summary, they describe how "TURN first" or "Relay first" is used to establish a connection first via TURN server and then for a number of seconds try to establish a peer to peer connection. This is supposed to minimize latency before the call is initiated for faster call start times. Chad says this kind of thing is possible if you modify the core WebRTC stack.

Is there a way to implement faster TURN first connections in the browser or is this only possible with a custom implementation of WebRTC?

If not, are there any open source examples of a TURN first implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options for this:
1) set the ice policy to relay, establish a call, then change the ice policy to all and do an ice restart. This is the best in terms of performance, the ice restart costs quite a bit though. Requires setConfiguration which is only available in Chrome 58+, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4591#c26 for details.

2) change the order of addIceCandidate calls and only add candidates with type relay initally. After the ice connection state changes to connected, add all other candidates. This works but only approximates the performance.

3) if you are using the native webrtc stack, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4591 implemented an option for this. Its not exposed to Javascript sadly.

Comment: I would additionally suggest to enforce TURN by policy in case one determined to be behind a symmetrical NAT. That at least prevents TURN to come in unnecessarily. But I’m not sure if this covers 100% of the cases.

Comment: attempts to determine what NAT type you're behind have turned out to be impractical. Hence we have ICE.

Comment: Hmm. Really? What do you think about your own hack today, which still works fine for me? :) https://webrtchacks.com/symmetric-nat/